# Hide MasterViewController when clicking a button

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.3, show-hide, master-detail

I have a Master/Detail application and everything works right..i added a button with the purpose of taking me to another tableViewController. 
I need, when i go to that table view controller, to hide permanently the master view controller from portrait and landscape mode.
So to recapitulate, i am in a newly created table view controller independent from the original Detail View Controller, and i need to hide permanently the master view controller when this button is clicked and the new TableViewController is loaded..
How can i do it ? I tried to use a MGSplitViewController but i got lost using it..i'm a newb in Xcode development. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Update 1:
My problem is not with the Detail View Controller...in the Detail ViewCOntroller i have added a button that will take me to another tableviewcontroller...now when i load that i need to force the masterviewcontroller to stay hidden how can i do it?

Comment: Please check this http://cl.ly/3F0c1r3r2c2z3S09241p

Answer (score -1):

Once you configure your detail view controller, you need to need to dismiss the popover controller.

```
if (self.popoverController) {
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

If your detail view controller doesn't already have a property to hold the UIPopoverController, you can capture it by implementing these delegate methods for UISplitViewControllerDelegate

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)iSplitViewController
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)iViewController
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)iBarButtonItem
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)iPopoverController {

    self.popoverController = iPopoverController;
}


- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)iSplitViewController
     willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)iViewController
  invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)iBarButtonItem {

    self.popoverController = nil;
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with popovers

Comment: My problem is not with the Detail View Controller...in the Detail ViewCOntroller i have added a button that will take me to another tableviewcontroller...now when i load that i need to force the masterviewcontroller to stay hidden how can i do it?